# How can we check which tiles clicked in sap ui5? and what is the approach to call different based on tiles clicked?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

[image: Tiles SAP UI5]
As displayed above i created some tiles in UI5 and now i want to perform different operations based on each tiles clicked?

So i used events in my view.js like (onPressTileOne, onPressTileTwo) while clicking on tiles i am printing alert message in controller but if so many tiles are there then what should i do i don't want to write event for each tile

please tell me how to check which tiles is clicked?
Here is my controller code--

```
sap.ui.controller("view.Main", {
handleEditPress : function (evt) {
    var oTileContainer = this.getView().byId("container");
    var newValue = ! oTileContainer.getEditable();
    oTileContainer.setEditable(newValue);
    evt.getSource().setText(newValue ? "Done" : "Edit");
  },
  handleTileDelete : function (evt) {
    var tile = evt.getParameter("tile");
    evt.getSource().removeTile(tile);
  },
  onPressTileOne : function (evt) {
        alert("Tiles1 Pressed...");
      },
  onPressTileTwo : function (evt) {
        alert("Tiles2 Pressed...");       
      } ,
      onPressTileThree : function (evt) {
         alert("Tiles3 Pressed...");
      }
     });
```

Comment: By which property you are going to distinguish the tiles?

Comment: by clicking on tiles i want to call separate functions for each tiles. so can click event distinguish the tiles? and i want to do this without creating events in view.js

Comment: oEvent.getSource() - will return you the tile object